# How to open working directory directly from R console?

Tags: r

How can I open my `getwd()` folder directly from the R console? This is useful if I want to see something I've recently just exported there. A google search has revealed nothing and I don't have the capability to build a function.

Comment: you can see the contents with `list.files(getwd())`

Comment: **Of course** you can build a function. `mydir <- function() list.files()` just created `mydir` (and the `getwd()` is done automagically if we do not supply a different directory).

Comment: If using Windows, you might also try `choose.files(getwd())`.

Comment: Also on a windows machine: `shell.exec(getwd())`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you actually want a file browser you could create a function to open the directory.  This is done differently based on the operating system you're using but this should cover most bases

```
opendir <- function(dir = getwd()){
    if (.Platform['OS.type'] == "windows"){
        shell.exec(dir)
    } else {
        system(paste(Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER"), dir))
    }
}
```

If you don't need it to be cross platform you can reduce it down to just the code for your OS.  But if you just want to view the files in a given directory then using `dir` should be good enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dir()` or `list.files()` to display the files in the current working directory or `file.choose()` to browse the directory and choose a file. All three default to the current working directory.

Answer (score 4):

Posting an answer because the above function did not work for me - got around it buusing a macOS terminal command via a `system` call from within R (session info below).

**Function**

```
opendir <- function(directory = getwd()){
  system(sprintf('open %s', shQuote(directory)))
}
```

**Session Info**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] here_0.1          htmlwidgets_1.3  
 [3] openxlsx_4.1.0.1  tictoc_1.0       
 [5] plotly_4.9.0      jsonlite_1.6     
 [7] ggplot2_3.1.1     lubridate_1.7.4  
 [9] httr_1.4.0        data.table_1.12.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.0.2          Rcpp_1.0.1        
 [3] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 later_0.8.0       
 [5] pillar_1.4.0       compiler_3.6.0    
 [7] plyr_1.8.4         tools_3.6.0       
 [9] digest_0.6.19      packrat_0.5.0     
[11] tibble_2.1.1       gtable_0.3.0      
[13] viridisLite_0.3.0  pkgconfig_2.0.2   
[15] rlang_0.3.4        shiny_1.3.2       
[17] rstudioapi_0.10    crosstalk_1.0.0   
[19] yaml_2.2.0         withr_2.1.2       
[21] dplyr_0.8.1        stringr_1.4.0     
[23] rprojroot_1.3-2    grid_3.6.0        
[25] tidyselect_0.2.5   glue_1.3.1        
[27] R6_2.4.0           processx_3.3.1    
[29] purrr_0.3.2        tidyr_0.8.3       
[31] magrittr_1.5       ps_1.3.0          
[33] promises_1.0.1     backports_1.1.4   
[35] scales_1.0.0       htmltools_0.3.6   
[37] assertthat_0.2.1   xtable_1.8-4      
[39] mime_0.6           colorspace_1.4-1  
[41] httpuv_1.5.1       labeling_0.3      
[43] stringi_1.4.3      lazyeval_0.2.2    
[45] munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using:

```
utils::browseURL(getwd())
```

---

Another useful snippet in this context:

```
lapply(.libPaths(), browseURL)
```

Comment: Simple and efficient