# Is there a library to provide a better decision tree picture or is there another way to make my decision tree easier to read in R?

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree

I have a classification model using the c5.0 algorithm with a script like this. 
`pola = C5.0(train_set[,-8], train_set[,8])`

Then I display the decision tree with this script.
`plot(pola, type="s", main="Decision Tree")`

And the results of the post give the writing attributes that overlap with each other like in this picture.
[image]

So, is there a library to provide a better tree picture or is there another way to make my tree easier to read?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem sees to be "size" rather than a bad decision tree graph. One option would be to save it as an image and open it externally with much greater size. Eg something similar to:

```
png(file = 'mytree.png', width = 920, height = 1260)
plot(pola, type="s", main="Decision Tree")
dev.off()
# Open directory with image 
if (.Platform['OS.type'] == "windows"){
    shell.exec(getwd())
} else {
    system(paste(Sys.getenv("R_BROWSER"), getwd()))
}
```

This of course this will make it so, that you might have to scroll around to see the individual parts of the tree.

(credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135823/10782538), for inspiration to open file explorer through R)